# Remove parent if no children

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 entities with a ManyToOne relation. And when I delete a child I want delete the parent only if there is no other children bind to the parent.

But I don't understand how to do that. If I do a cascade delete, I've a constrainst error, because Doctrine try to delete the parent when I delete a child but it has other children. With orphanRemoval it's not possible to, because the children are on the Many side, and if I put it on the One side it doesn't work (I never delete the parent directly).

Answer (score 0):

What if you retrive the parent before deleting the child, then after have deleted the child you check for remaining children of the parent, and if there aren't you delete the parent as well?

```
$parent = $child->getParent();
//remove $child
if(count($parent->getChildren())==0){
    //delete $parent
}
```

Comment: I think I can do this in a preRemove/postRemove subscriber, that's right. But maybe there is an other solution directly with Doctrine ?

Comment: I haven't found and never user other solutions. As you said, you can't use neither orphanRemoval nor cascade, so I guess you gotta go with this way.